# Variable permanentemente disponible en controller Cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp

Quiero tener una variable que se llena con una consulta que este disponible para todas las vistas de mi controller en cake php

```
$number = $this ->Mesas->find('all')
            ->where(['user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
            ->count(); 

    $this->set('number');
    $this->set('_serialize', ['number']);
```

Quiero tener disponible la variable $numero para todas mis vistas (actualmente tengo copiado ese código en todas mis actions) pero acabo de comenzar con Cakephp y quiero aprender a manejarlo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

En el AppController, crea la función, yo cambiaría el nombre de la variable a algo menos frecuente y mejor definido como numeroMesas, pero te pongo el ejemplo como lo tienes tu.

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $number = TableRegistry::get('Mesas');

    $number = $this ->Mesas->find('all')
        ->where(['user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
        ->count(); 

$this->set(['number' => $number]);
$this->set('_serialize', ['number']);
}
```